# how to generate and download images in storage using laravel's faker?

Tags: php, laravel, faker

how to generate and download images in storage using laravel's faker?

I want when running seeders to download images and save them automatically in the storage/categories folder, but when running seeder the images are downloaded all for a second and then they disappear or are deleted, so I don't know what is happening.

this is CategoryFactory

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'image' => 'categories/' . $this->faker->image(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public/categories'),640, 480, null, false)
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Storage::makeDirectory('categories')` will create a directory at `storage/app/categories` if the driver is set to `public`. So when using with `faker->image()` the path needs to be `storage_path('app/dummy')`.

```php
'image' => 'categories/' . $this->faker->image(storage_path('app/categories'),640, 480, null, false)
```

Comment: get this error: Cannot write to directory  `"C:\appName\storage\app/categories"`

Comment: That's a directory permission issue and probably you are on windows, so I don't know how to set those. You could try `$this->faker->image(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'categories'),640, 480, null, false)` if it has anything to do with the directory separator.

Comment: Hello, thanks, but I still get the same error now, but this time if the path Cannot write to directory "C:\eCommerce-TALL\storage\app\categories" works well, then I think it may be due to directory permissions in windows, but I have already given all the permissions to the storage folder, here you can see the error in detail [link](https://prnt.sc/K0WcQJTVcaKr)